# How to use bin in python without 0b from start

Tags: python

I've been searching everywhere but i couldn't find anything about this. What i want is really clear and normal.

This is what i want:

```
>>> bin(26)
>>> '11010'
```

And don't tell me to use `format` because `bin` is so much faster and when i use `bin(26)[2:]` it's speed decreasess extremly.

```
from time import time
a = time()
for i in range(100000):
    bin(i)
print(time() - a) # 0.0

a = time()
for i in range(100000):
    bin(i)[2:].zfill(8)
print(time() - a) # 0.022130966186523438

a = time()
for i in range(100000):
    format(i,'b')
print(time() - a) # 0.015463829040527344

a = time()
for i in range(100000):
    format(i,'08b')
print(time() - a) # 0.031238079071044922

# Edit

a = time()
for i in range(100000):
    bin(i)[2:]
print(time() - a) # 0.02191925048828125
```

Comment: The second time doesn't just use `[2:]`, it uses `[2:].zfill(8)`.  I imagine most of the delay is from the zfill, not the slice.

Comment: Code block updated.

Comment: Why are some solutions forcing eight bits? Do you want that or not?

Comment: So `[2:].zfill(8)` was **faster** than plain `[2:]`? That seems very suspicious.

Comment: bin(i)[2:] and f'{i:b}' have very similar performance characteristics

Comment: A time of '0' would make me immediately very suspicious, additional to what @JohnGordon raised. For profiling I prefer if my task to take around one second, not tiny fractions. Doing so reduces the impact of various sources of noise.